# Como ordenar um select trazendo resultados de 2 em 2

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando um sistema onde o usuário informa o nome e hora de nascimento. 
Gostaria de saber se é possível resolver a seguinte questão:
Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: Como é]

Tendo o nome e a hora de nascimento, o administrador do sistema informa qual a prioridade de cada registro, sendo:

1 = muito prioritário, 2 = prioritário, 3 = pouco prioritário, 4 = não prioritário. 
Depois quero que esses registros sejam exibidos em ordem de prioridade, e de 2 em 2. Exemplo: 2 registros de prioridade 1... depois 2 registros de prioridade 2... dois de prioridade 3...etc 
Não, precisa necessariamente ser no mesmo select, poderia usar mais de um select, porém enquanto houver registros, preciso listar de 2 em 2, sem repeti-los.
Ficaria assim:

[image: Como eu quero que fique]

Estou usando MySql e Php. Alguem tem alguma idéia de como posso fazer isso? Obrigado!

Segue a tabela do mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_nasc_users` (
  `id` int(111) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `hr_nasc` time NOT NULL,
  `prioridade` int(9) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbl_nasc_users` (`id`, `nome`, `hr_nasc`, `prioridade`) VALUES
(1, 'Pedro', '17:34:40', 1),
(2, 'João', '17:23:18', 2),
(3, 'Marcos', '17:56:39', 2),
(4, 'Vinicius', '18:12:48', 1),
(5, 'Miguel', '18:36:53', 3),
(6, 'Bruno', '18:30:10', 4),
(7, 'Felipe', '18:48:42', 3),
(8, 'Antonio', '19:34:40', 1),
(9, 'Victor', '19:23:18', 2),
(10, 'Ronaldo', '19:56:39', 2),
(11, 'Ricardo', '20:12:48', 1),
(12, 'Teodoro', '20:36:53', 3),
(13, 'Gabriel', '21:30:10', 4),
(14, 'Patrick', '22:48:42', 3);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_nasc_users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tbl_nasc_users`
  MODIFY `id` int(111) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

Comment: Se a ordenação deverá ser do menor para o maior, por quê aparecem números menores que 4 ao final da lista?

Comment: Yago, nestes casos não vai ser uma ordenação muito natural, pois o "Pedro" e o "Vinicios" podem aparecer no começo como também podem aparecer o "Antonio" e o "Ricardo". Tem algum outro critério nesta ordem?

Comment: Se ele ordenar da menor para a maior a ordenação ficará assim: 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5  Como você quer diferente, precisa criar um critério para ser utilizado.

Comment: Então pessoal, é um sistema onde o usuario informa o nome e hora de nascimento. Depois eu que informo qual a prioridade de cada registro, sendo, 1 = muito prioritário, 2 = prioritário, 3 = pouco prioritário e 4 = não prioritário. Depois quero que esses registros sejam exibidos em ordem de prioridade, e de 2 em 2. Exemplo: 2 registros de prioridade 1... depois 2 registros de prioridade 2... dois de prioridade 3...etc
Não, precisa necessariamente ser no mesmo select, poderia usar mais de um select, porém enquanto houver registros, preciso listar de 2 em 2, sem repetir.

Comment: Não consigo pensar em um critério que atenda essa necessidade.
Eu pensei em criar um select para cada prioridade, usando LIMIT 2. Porém, como faço para o resultado continuar seguindo sequencia?

Comment: A questão é: por quê, no seu exemplo, aparecem registros com "muito prioritário" após registros com "não prioritário", visto que deseja ordem crescente? Esta parte que não está clara. Sempre que chegar na prioridade 4 a numeração deve voltar a 1?

Comment: Exatamente Anderson! Quando chegar na 4 ele volta a exibir a prioridade 1. A idéia é essa! Se ainda houver registros com prioridade 1 ele vai continuar mostrando de 2 em 2 sempre

Comment: Talvez `union` possa ajudar com uma subquery - mas não estou 100% certo disso.

Comment: Papa Charlie, Tentei usar o seguinte:
(SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE prioridade = 1 ORDER by hora_nasc ASC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE prioridade = 2 ORDER by hora_nasc ASC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE prioridade = 3 ORDER by hora_nasc ASC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE prioridade = 4 ORDER by hora_nasc ASC LIMIT 2)

Isso até resolve meu problema, porém, eu preciso continuar o select enquanto houver registros, mas sem repetir os que ja foram exibidos.

Comment: @YagoLima, consegue disponibilizar os dados da tabela como uma tabela mesmo? Estão em formato de imagem e assim fica dificil copiá-los para simular testes.

Comment: @jlHertel postei! Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que é o administrador que informa a prioridade, eu pensei que ele poderia 'agrupar' por horario. O campo prioridade foi dividido em dois, há uma prioridade separada por 'primeira hora', 'segunda hora', etc. Uma procedure para priorizar esses pessoal poderia ser facilmente criada.

A tabela ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_nasc_users (  id int NOT NULL,  nome varchar(30) NOT NULL, hr_nasc time NOT NULL,  prioridade int NOT NULL, horario int not null )
```

E o administrador poderia classifica-los assim:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_nasc_users (id, nome, hr_nasc, prioridade,horario) VALUES    (1, 'Pedro', '17:34:40', 1, 1), (2, 'João', '17:23:18', 2, 1), (3, 'Marcos', '17:56:39', 2, 1), (4, 'Vinicius', '18:12:48', 1,1), 
 (5, 'Miguel', '18:36:53', 3,2), (6, 'Bruno', '18:30:10', 4,2), (7, 'Felipe', '18:48:42', 3,2), (8, 'Antonio', '19:34:40', 1,3), (9, 'Victor', '19:23:18', 2,3), 
 (10, 'Ronaldo', '19:56:39', 2,4), (11, 'Ricardo', '20:12:48', 1,4), (12, 'Teodoro', '20:36:53', 3,4), (13, 'Gabriel', '21:30:10', 4,4), (14, 'Patrick', '22:48:42', 3,4);
```

Então o retorno seria simples:

```
select * from tbl_nasc_users order by horario, prioridade
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Reginaldo, obrigado pela idéia! Testei aqui, e vi que é possivel fazer da maneira que você indicou. Inclusive, desta forma, posso optar por trazer os dados de 2 em 2 registros, ou de 3 em 3, ou 4 em 4.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ir somando a quantidade de registros e utilizar isso em uma fórmula matemática. O unico problema disso é que você fica limitado as quatro prioridades que você definiu, mas caso elas sejam fixas em seu banco não vejo problemas.

Esta consulta deve trazer o resultado esperado:

```
SET @qtd_1 = 0;
SET @qtd_2 = 0;
SET @qtd_3 = 0;
SET @qtd_4 = 0;

SET @aux_1 = false;
SET @aux_2 = false;
SET @aux_3 = false;
SET @aux_4 = false;

SELECT
nome, prioridade,
(CASE prioridade
  WHEN 1 THEN
    ((@qtd_1 := @qtd_1 + IF(@aux_1 := !@aux_1, 1, 0)) * 100) + prioridade
  WHEN 2 THEN
    ((@qtd_2 := @qtd_2 + IF(@aux_2 := !@aux_2, 1, 0)) * 100) + prioridade
  WHEN 3 THEN
    ((@qtd_3 := @qtd_3 + IF(@aux_3 := !@aux_3, 1, 0)) * 100) + prioridade
  WHEN 4 THEN
    ((@qtd_4 := @qtd_4 + IF(@aux_4 := !@aux_4, 1, 0)) * 100) + prioridade
  ELSE 0 END) AS prioridade_real
FROM minha_tabela
ORDER BY prioridade_real;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado @JHertel, eu testei aqui, funcionou muito bem! As 4 prioridades são fixas sim.
Sou novo no mysql, e sinceramente, estou aqui tentando entender oque o a query esta fazendo. 
Fiquei com uma duvida... É possível "optar" entre exibir de 2 em 2 registros ou de 3 em 3 ou de 4 em 4?

Comment: @YagoLima, a query está usando um operador lógico para saber se agrupa ou não. Você pode utilizar um operador de soma e mudar a forma como agrupa os registros, mas isso vai demandar uma lógica um pouco diferente. TL;DR; Não, está fixo em 2

Comment: @YagoLima, Observe o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como agradecer.